# Regex for 1 or 2 characters after slash

Tags: php, regex, digits, slash

I have a list of IP's in CIDR notation in a php script like

```
    $str .= '123.23.23.4/17,';
    $str .= '123.23.23.4/23,';
    $str .= '123.23.23.4/8,';
    $str .= '123.23.23.4/18';
```

I'm trying to get all of the numbers after the slash. The possible range is 1 - 31. From examples I found here I tried this
3
preg_match_all("//[1-3][0-9]/", $str, $matches);

which gave

```
    /17
    /23
    /18
```

Then I tried

```
    preg_match_all("/\/[1-31]{1,2}/", $str, $matches);

    /1
    /23
    /1
```

So the /8 is being missed in both cases and the second returns the wrong number. Can someone provide the correct command to do this, please?

Comment: Looks like you could just explode on `,`, and then explode on `/`, too

Comment: [Quick demo](https://3v4l.org/u5eNH) of what I said. I generally like to avoid RegEx until it is absolutely needed, but that is a personal preference. The demo is more verbose, with more lines, but I would argue it is easier to scan, especially if it included comments explaining the data that it was consuming. It will also, depending on your real data, give you the chance to find exceptions to your logic, which a RegEx might pass over.

Answer (score 3):

Using `\/[1-3][0-9]` matches at least 2 digits, from 11 till 39

Using `[1-31]{1,2}` is the same as `[1-3]{1,2}` and matches 1 or 2 times a range 1-3

If you only want the numbers using php:

```
/\K(?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\b
```

If you want to make the pattern more specific you can see this page to [match an ip number](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html).

The pattern matches:

- `/` Match a forward slash (Using a different delimiter like `~` you don't have to escape the `\/`)
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `(?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` Match 1-9 or 10-29 or 30 or 31
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ONKdwU/1) and a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/5aQZM).

```
$str = '123.23.23.4/17,';
$str .= '123.23.23.4/23,';
$str .= '123.23.23.4/8,';
$str .= '123.23.23.4/18';

preg_match_all("~/\K(?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\b~", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 17
    [1] => 23
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 18
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and example. That worked except that I got an Unknown modifier error for the /k. I changed it to \/k and it ran and gave the correct output.